# Optimize jquery plugin "on" method extension

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like feedback on how to optimize this jQuery plugin used for triggering change event on any DOM element.
This plugin doesn't use a timer to check for DOM changes but instead extends some jQuery native functions.
I'm mostly concerned by the `.on()` method extension because I'm sure there is better way of doing this.

[jsFiddle to test](http://jsfiddle.net/UZcJu/)

```
;(function ($) {
    var fctsToObserve = {
        append: [$.fn.append, 'self'],
        prepend: [$.fn.prepend, 'self'],
        remove: [$.fn.remove, 'parent'],
        before: [$.fn.before, 'parent'],
        after: [$.fn.after, 'parent']
    }, fctsObserveKeys = '';
    $.each(fctsToObserve, function (key, element) {
        fctsObserveKeys += "hasChanged." + key + " ";
    });
    var oOn = $.fn.on;
    $.fn.on = function () {
        if (arguments[0].indexOf('hasChanged') != -1) arguments[0] += " " + fctsObserveKeys;
        return oOn.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    $.fn.hasChanged = function (types, data, fn) {
        return this.on(fctsObserveKeys, types, null, data, fn);
    };
    $.extend($, {
        observeMethods: function (namespace) {
            var namespace = namespace ? "." + namespace : "";
            var _len = $.fn.length;
            delete $.fn.length;
            $.each(fctsToObserve, function (key) {
                var _pre = this;
                $.fn[key] = function () { 
                    var target = _pre[1] === 'self' ? this : this.parent(),
                        ret = _pre[0].apply(this, arguments);
                    target.trigger("hasChanged." + key + namespace, arguments);
                    return ret;
                };
            });
            $.fn.length = _len;
        }
    });
    $.observeMethods()
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Something you should check out: **Pub/Sub**. An awesome way of setting up, turning off, and triggering events. Links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh201955.aspx
https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/1321768

Comment: Oh yeah also you might want to check for elements that already have this functionality "built in" so you're not repeating or overriding those presets. Elements like `select`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if there is a better way to do it, but it seems quite smart and minimally intrusive.

From a once over style perspective:

- `function (key, element)` <- since you dont use element, you can remove it from the signature
- This

  ```
  $.each(fctsToObserve, function (key, element) {
    fctsObserveKeys += "hasChanged." + key + " ";
  });
  ```

  would have been better served with `Array.reduce`, not sure if you want to support [browsers that don't have `Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Browser_compatibility)
- Naming.. Any code reviewer would be remiss if they did not point that you abbreviate your variables too much which makes the code needlessly harder to understand
- In the `if` in `$.fn.on = function () {` you should use curly braces or a least a newline.
- There is no point in declaring `var namespace` here:

  ```
  observeMethods: function (namespace) {
      var namespace = namespace ? "." + namespace : "";
  ```

  just go for

  ```
  observeMethods: function (namespace) {
      namespace = namespace ? "." + namespace : "";
  ```
- Comments, some of the more trickier concepts could have used a line of comment